# Reverse Engineer this processing in lightroom

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, aperture, reverse-engineering, adobe

Wondering if anyone can put a quick eye on these photos below and share what develop edits in Adobe Lightroom they think could help create a similar style in other photos.

These were taken by Outdoor Magazine editor Nick Kelley on a recent trip to Argentina. Here is the link, with camera setup information below each photo. Unfortunately the camera I use is 18-55 and I can't bring aperture below 4.6. So I need to find a way to recreate that as well. I'm specifically looking at the 2nd, 10th, 11th, 12th and 15th photos in the essay series.

Thanks for any and all help.

http://yeticoolers.com/pages/blog/patagonia-gauchos-brown-trout-and-mate/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=nick-kelley-patagonia

[image: Sony a7rII with Sony 24-70mm f/4, 1/1600 second, f/8, ISO 2500]

Comment: Can you describe what you are seeing in those photos that you want to replicate? They look a bit desaturated to me maybe, but there is nothing obvious to me, so not sure what you're after

Comment: Without a more detailed description of "this" in the "headline", the question is useless and indistinguishable from every other "how did they do this" question.

Comment: You should contact the photographer directly; I am certain he will be very happy to discuss the techniques he used for the photos.

Answer (score 1):

Add some vignetting, clarity, and selectively desaturate or just desaturate.

Obviously your equipment is going to hold you back.  These images were shot with an extremely advanced state of the art full frame camera and a wide variety of lenses that you simply won't be able to recreate the effects of very well. One cannot simply recreate a $3,000 Leica lens with some clever Photoshop Lightroom techniques. It also doesn't hurt to travel to a place as beautiful as Patagonia.

One piece I wasn't able to completely put my finger on is if some of the images used a grad neutral density or if that was added in post, but it seems as though something along those lines was impactful to the end result.

Comment: It may be selective desaturation, but I'm leaning more towards the difference between two different species of tree. The overlap about 2/3 to the right in the upper half of the frame would be nearly impossible to pull off in post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like film to me. It could be a film preset.

Comment: All of the shots at the linked article were taken with a Sony a7rII (except 2 aerial shots taken by a DJI drone). I got the distinct impression of some film-like color grading in post, maybe VSCO?